# Using jquery.fileupload.rails, the function .fileupload() sometimes fails to return

Tags: jquery, ruby, file-upload, blueimp

Q: Why would .fileupload() fail to return?       (the question in a nutshell)

Details:

I use blueimp's JQuery's fileupload to successfully drag-n-drop files, which are then handled by CarrierWave.  Most of the time it initializes properly.

I have a nested-tab interface (bootstrap) which accepts different fileuploads to different targets depending on your selected tab. This also works. Most of the time, everything initializes correctly, and I'm happy.

**But fairly frequently the .fileupload() function doesn't return (crashes) without any displayed error messages on client or server. I'm trying to figure out why.**

(note: The word "history" here refers to my data and not browser history.)

The displayed data is loaded by an ajax call. 
The `form_for` and `<script>` are contained in a partial: records/_fileupload.html.erb (showed below)
The partial is *not* loaded by that ajax call.

```
<div class="container span9">
  <%= form_for Record.new, :remote => true, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload-history"  } do |f| %>
    ....
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar" id="fileupload-droptarget-history">
    ....
      <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
        <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
      </div>
  ....

<!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
<div class="fileupload-loading"></div>

<!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
<table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>

....
<!-- standard "template-upload" template from example code -->
<script id="template-upload-fileupload-history" type="text/x-tmpl">
....

<!-- Empty template to display files available for download (unused) -->
<script id="template-download-history" type="text/x-tmpl"></script>
```

Continuing in the same file, notice the `$(function ()...` used to run the script after the page finishes loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(function () {
```

This alert will fire...

```
   alert("fileupload history fileupload.html.erb - A");

   // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
   $('#fileupload-history').fileupload({
     uploadTemplateId: "template-upload-fileupload-history",
     downloadTemplateId: "template-download-history",
     dropZone: $("#fileupload-droptarget-history")
   });
```

But the following alert will occasionally not fire, indicating .fileupload() never returned (crashed).

```
   alert("fileupload history fileupload.html.erb - B");
```

To complete my example here are some helpful bits for people who happen to be looking at this code.  This first one is to refresh my displayed data after the upload completes.

```
   $('#fileupload-history').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
     fillHistoryAjaxHolder($("#currentAJAXHistoryUrl").html());
   });
```

...and this one restricts the drag-and-drop to only the designated drop target.

```
   // Disable drag-n-drop for the rest of the page
   $(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   });
 });
</script>
```

So my question:

What would cause .fileupload to not return some-of-the-time?
(depending on how I get to my page... or on what was loaded previously)

So I wonder if there is some sort of initialization that is supposed to happen prior to this point?

Now, to complicate things:

I previously had multiple instances of the templates and even of the `id="fileupload"` which was copied around to numerous files. But, I realized that I was running into different target problems so I changed my `id="fileupload"` to be `id="fileupload-history"` in this case, and `id="fileupload-report"` in another case, and so on. The idea was to split every instance of the fileupload into its own distinct parts.

But, when I stripped out my old (duplicated) code, the `.fileupload()` failure started happening more frequently. (now it fails quite reliably)

So (Finally!) my questions to experienced JQuery fileupload users:

- For multiple upload targets, should I be using different `form_for` `id='tag'` tags?

I ask because the following example uses the same element for different calls to .fileupload()

Example from github: ["Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page"](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page):

```
$('.fileupload').each(function () {
    $(this).fileupload({
        dropZone: $(this)
    });
});
```

- So, is there a problem with using different `$('.fileupload')` elements?
- Is there a place I should be looking for error messages that I might not be checking?

  - Currently I'm not seeing anything in Google Chrome's Developer Tools's usual place.
- Any thoughts?

Long post, sorry.

Comment: Resolution: It turned out that the problem was the order of includes.

Adding the line:

    <%= javascript_include_tag  "jquery-fileupload.js" %>

...at the appropriate spot brought it in more reliably than its previous location.